# form with filters including and/or condition and database design

Tags: forms, filter, database-design

I am trying to build a form where user can set certain filters and conditions.

For example: I have the following field in the employee table database

```
Employee Table
1. ID
2. Name
3. State
4. County


Department
1. ID
2. Name
```

I would want the user to select conditions like and also want to save this information for further processing

```
1) Name = 'abc' and state = 'pqr' AND department.name = 'efg'
2) Name = 'abc' and (state = 'pqr' OR department.name = 'efg')
3) Name = 'abc' OR (state = 'pqr' OR department.name = 'efg')
```

Any help on the best practices or approaches for form and table design on this would be really helpful.

Thanks.